# Unable to apply Google Font to Ionic2 project

Tags: ionic2, google-font-api

I am unable to apply Google Fonts API to my Ionic2 project. Here's what I tried:

**`app.scss`**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif !important;

}

html, body {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif !important;
}
```

**`index.html`**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" rel="stylesheet">
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`app.scss`**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz);

// Font Variables
$yanone-kaffeesatz: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif !important;

// Styles
html, body {
  font-family: $yanone-kaffeesatz;
}
```

local use

assets/custom-fonts/YanoneKaffeesatz-Regular.ttf

on theme/**`variables.scss`**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'yanone-kaffeesatz';
  src: url('../assets/custom-fonts/YanoneKaffeesatz-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: better approach with Ionic2 is to download the fonts and store it locally in case you want an offline implementation in the future.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work. I also tried adding the `@import` to `variables.scss` and also download the file for offline use and stored it at `assets/fonts/`, but all in vain.

Comment: In this case, the file type is `.woff` not `.ttf`. And I understand this should work for sure, but something is preventing this font from being applied The `Chrome Developer Tools` shows the font-family has been applied, but I see no font change. It won't apply any other font (like Monotype Corsiva or Comic Sans) either. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time.